# Java Scanner from second method

Tags: java

I am having problem to invoke Scanner class from second method in main method. My code is this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    
    static void checkAge(int age){
        Scanner new_age = new Scanner(System.in);
        age = new_age.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your age");
        if(age < 18){
            System.out.println("You are a minor");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You are of apropriate age");
        
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        checkAge();
    }
}
```

I get an error:

> Main.java:18: error: '.class' expected
> checkAge(Scanner.new_age(int));
> ^ 1 error

Comment: You didn't pass argument in method when call `checkAge();` but your method expect arguments `checkAge(int age)`. You can remove `int age` from parameter if you take input for that

Comment: That exception doesn't match that code.

Comment: When I run this code, I get this: `error: method checkAge in class Main cannot be applied to given types; checkAge();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call you function with arguments : checkAge(18); or checkAge(15);as you checkAge() requires parameters to check the conditions.

Comment: Thanks for response. Strange thing is that I get an error "Resource leak: 'new_age' is never closed" in VS Code. Code is setup for java development. When I make new class in Intellij with the same code, than build and compilation is in order.